# How to get the data from promise when i cant get forEach is not a function?

Tags: javascript

i have an a data using fetch on some API and looks like this.

[image]

and i'm fetching this data (as you can see), i'm using a promise here is the code

**data-source**

```
const baseUrl = "https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1";
const apiKey = "78fa4727ab9c4495d4fc07dae75f775b";
const chartTrackPopular = "chart.tracks.get? 
chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=jp&f_has_lyrics=1";
const chartTrackAll = "chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=5&country=us&f_has_lyrics=1";


class DataSource {

// initialize the data 
static getPopularLirik(){
    return fetch(`${baseUrl}/${chartTrackPopular}&apikey=${apiKey}`)
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(responseJson => {
            if(responseJson.message.body.track_list) {
                return Promise.resolve(responseJson.message.body.track_list);
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(`error`)
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}

export default DataSource;
```

i get the data but when i try to loop it, i cant get the data. Here is how i want to get the data

**popular-list.js**

```
import './popular-item.js'

class PopularList extends HTMLElement {

constructor(){
    super();
    this.shadowDOM = this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
}

set items(item){
    this._item = item;
    this.render();
}

render(){
    this.shadowDOM.innerHTML = "";
    this._item.forEach(musicitem => {
        const itemElements = document.createElement("popular-item");
        itemElements.items = musicitem;

        // this.shadowDOM.appendChild(itemElements);
    })
    // let result = DataSource.getPopularLirik();
    // console.log(this._item.track);
}
};
customElements.define("popular-list", PopularList);
```

and this is the error i got

```
VM55555 popular-list.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: this._item.forEach is not a function
at HTMLElement.render (VM55555 popular-list.js:20)
at HTMLElement.set items [as items] (VM55555 popular-list.js:15)
at renderResult (VM55554 main.js:13)
at HTMLDocument.main (VM55554 main.js:19
```

i don't know how and why this can be happened, i thought if i try to loop the data i can get the value but i dont even cant to forEach it. How do i resolve this?

Comment: Why can't you say `for (var musicitem in this._item) ....` ?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with `getPopularLirik` or the fact that it returns a promise. You never set the `.items` (or `._item`) of the `PopularList` instance?!